# What does Error [sqlite3_rtree_geometry_callback is not found] mean in qgis 1.8 with windows 7 64 bit?

Tags: qgis, sqlite, windows-7, 64bit

qgis1.8 does not open. I get a message that sqlite3_rtree_geometry_callback is not found

Comment: Welcome to GIS-SE!  Your question has been flagged up in the review queue as being of low quality doe to its short length.  Would you be able to use the edit button to provide more details like the steps you took to try and install, and then debug it, please?

Answer (score 2):

Paul,

The solution is to rename the following DLL from:

C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\DLLs\sqlite3.dll

to:

C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\DLLs\xxsqlite3.dll

There are two versions of this dll that ship with the OSGeo4W installer which I bet is what you are using.  This change doesn't affect Python.  When it doesn't see the dll because of the name change it searches the path and finds the other one which works just find.