# Qgis 1.8.0 throws error "Can not find the entry point sqlite3_rtree_geometry_callback"

Tags: qgis, spatialite, windows-8

Loading QGIS on Window 8 causes this problem:

`Can not find the entry point sqlite3_rtree_geometry_callback in the procedure of dynamic loading C:\....\Quantum GIS Lisboa \ bin \ spatialite.dll`

Everything worked properly for many months.

Comment: Welcome to SE.GIS !!! What program you are loading on windows 8? (Is this  the setup or extension?)

Comment: hi,i loading qgis.exe on windows 8

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does Error \[sqlite3\_rtree\_geometry\_callback is not found\] mean in qgis 1.8 with windows 7 64 bit?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70034/what-does-error-sqlite3-rtree-geometry-callback-is-not-found-mean-in-qgis-1-8)